# How to use type-graphql to call typeorm's BaseEntity when do a creation?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

Versions:

- typeorm: 0.3.6
- type-graphql: 1.1.1

The project directory likes:

```
- src/
    inputs/
      CreateBookInput.ts
    models/
      Book.ts
    resolvers/
      BookResolver.ts
    index.ts
```

It just creates a sample book feature.

src/inputs/CreateBookInput.ts

```
import { InputType, Field } from "type-graphql";

@InputType()
export class CreateBookInput {
  @Field()
  title: string;

  @Field()
  author: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  isPublished?: boolean;
}
```

src/models/Book.ts

```
import { Entity, BaseEntity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm";
import { ObjectType, Field, ID } from "type-graphql";

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Book extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Column()
  author: string;

  @Field(() => Boolean)
  @Column({ default: false })
  isPublished: boolean;
}
```

src/models/BookResolver.ts

```
import { Resolver, Query, Mutation, Arg } from "type-graphql";
import { Book } from "../models/Book";
import { CreateBookInput } from "../inputs/CreateBookInput";

@Resolver()
export class BookResolver {
  @Query(() => [Book])
  books() {
    return Book.find();
  }

  @Mutation(() => Book)
  async createBook(@Arg("data") data: CreateBookInput) {
    const book = Book.create(data);
    await book.save();
    return book;
  }
}
```

src/index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";

import { BookResolver } from "./resolvers/BookResolver";

async function main() {
  await createConnection();
  const schema = await buildSchema({ resolvers: [BookResolver] });
  const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });
  await server.listen(4000);
  console.log("Server has started!");
}

main();
```

When run the application, there is an error happened:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/resolvers/BookResolver.ts:20:30 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(this: (new () => Book) & typeof BaseEntity, entityLikeArray: DeepPartial<Book>[]): Book[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'CreateBookInput' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<Book>[]'.
      Type 'CreateBookInput' is missing the following properties from type 'DeepPartial<Book>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(this: (new () => BaseEntity) & typeof BaseEntity, entityLike: DeepPartial<BaseEntity>): BaseEntity', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'CreateBookInput' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<BaseEntity>'.

20     const book = Book.create(data);
                                ~~~~

src/resolvers/BookResolver.ts:21:16 - error TS2339: Property 'save' does not exist on type 'Book[]'.

21     await book.save();
```

The `Book.create(data);` seems use the [built-in method](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_repository_baseentity_.baseentity.html#create).

Why this error happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following approach. Create an instance of Book and assign the values from the input type to it.

```js
@Mutation(() => Book)
async createBook(@Arg("data") data: CreateBookInput) {
  const book = Book.create(Book, data);
  await book.save();
  return book;
}
```

or

```js
@Mutation(() => Book)
async createBook(@Arg("data") data: CreateBookInput) {
  const book = new Book();
  Object.assign(book, data);
  await book.save();
  return book;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do `YourEntity.create<YourEntity>(data);` if the data type does not match the entity type exactly